# Laravel queue:work not working with spatie/laravel-multitenancy

Tags: laravel, queue

Using Laravel 10, Mysql with spatie/laravel-multitenancy.

Settings in multitenancy.php

`'queues_are_tenant_aware_by_default' => true,`

Created a UserCreated Mailable which implements ShouldQueue

```
    <?php

namespace App\Mail\Tenant;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;


class UserCreated extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;
    use SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     */
    public function __construct(User $user, string $password)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

Using database as queue driver and mail is getting added in jobs table in respective tenant db.

```
 Mail::to($this->user->email)->send((new UserCreated($this->user)));
```

But when I run php artisan tenants:artisan "queue:work" it's throwing below error.

`local.ERROR: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on null {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function beginTransaction() on null at \\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Concerns\\ManagesTransactions.php:177)`

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using MongoDB with your Laravel application?

Comment: If possible share your code snippet too.

Comment: added some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

All jobs needs to be stored in landlord DB.

and then run

`php artisan queue:work`

jobs will execute and tenant will change as per job tenant id.